# Convert from string to byte strange behavior

Tags: c#, encoding, arrays

I have string like this "0100110011001" I want to  convert it to byte array such that the array contains zeros and ones the problem that after the conversion the array contains 49, 48 I don't why I tried many encoding for example I use the following code , and changed the encoding type

```
 System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            byte result = encoding.GetBytes(str);
```

any idea why that happen, and how to achieve the output I desire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

48 is ASCII code for 0 and 49 is ASCII code for 1. There are many ways you can perform the conversion of this string, but this should be enough for you to manage on your own. Good luck :)

Possible solution:

```
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static byte[] ToByteArray(this string str)
        {
            char[] arr = str.ToCharArray();
            byte[] byteArr = new byte[arr.Length];

            for (int i=0; i<arr.Length; ++i)
            {
                switch (arr[i])
                {
                    case '0': byteArr[i] = 0; break;
                    case '1': byteArr[i] = 1; break;
                    default: throw new Exception(arr[i]+" is not 0 or 1.");
                }
            }

            return byteArr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why both creating a `char[]` to start with? Just index into the string.

Comment: You are right, Jon. I remember doing that before. I don't know why I decided to create a char array this time.

Answer (score 8):

You're asking for the text of the characters '0' and '1' to be encoded using [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). In UTF-8, a '0' is represented by byte 48, and '1' is represented by byte 49. (Non-ASCII characters are represented by multiple bytes.)

It sounds like you really want a binary parser - you can use `Convert.ToByte(text, 2)` for a single byte, but I'm not sure there's anything in the framework to convert an arbitrary-length string to a byte array by parsing it as binary. I'm sure there are lots of third-party routines available on the net to do it though - it's not hard.

It's *very* important that you understand why your original code didn't work though - what `Encoding.GetBytes` is *really* for.

Comment: can I use LINQ to divide the string to byte array

Comment: If I were you I would write an extension. Check my answer.

Comment: +2 for _It's very important that you understand why your original code didn't work though - what Encoding.GetBytes is really for_!

Answer (score 2):

As a one line linq statement (not that i would recommend this solution).

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(this string source)
{
    return
        Regex.Matches(source.PadLeft(source.Length + source.Length % 8, '0'), "[01]{0,8}")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Where(m => m.Success && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Groups[0].Value))
        .Select(m => Convert.ToByte(m.Groups[0].Value, 2))
        .ToArray();
}
```